# Android : Credit card view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

So, Anybody know how to implement ViewPager to sliding credit cards with following design:

[image]

Need centering active current page and part showing left and right items.
I tried find solutions, they are not helped (PagerContainer from github by recommendation @Commansware ...)

**I not need creation credit card design, I need only functionality viewpager such as when showing cards need visible part of left and right sides items**

Comment: I think **vinay gaba** did this. [check out](https://github.com/vinaygaba/CreditCardView)

Comment: *Need centering active current page and part showing left and right items.

Comment: Could you solve the problem? I need the same like you. Thanks.

Comment: yes, i solve this problem, how to send padding and margin you can find from @Er. Kaushik Kajavadara answer, and you can found view pager transformation animations for scaling when scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Check below link shows nice work with images:

https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

or you can add following code to have viewpager like you want:

```
yourViewPager.setPadding(defaultGap, 0, defaultGap, 0);
yourViewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
yourViewPager.setPageMargin(halfGap);
```

On the viewpager set left and right padding, e.g. 20dp. Do also set the page margin on the viewpager, e.g. half of the pager padding. And do not forget to disable clip padding.

Comment: this is not helped

Comment: Try this, and add this to your app then modify views according to your design. As you may miss something thats why not working from above link.  https://gist.github.com/devunwired/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1